Bound on Rademacher complexity using polynomial discrimination
This is lemma 4.14 in Wainwright's textbook on High-Dimensional Statistics, it states that given a class of function $\mathcal{F}$ has polynomial discrimination of order $v$, then for all integer $n$ and $x_1^n = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, we have the bound
$$
E_{\epsilon} \left[ \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i f(x_i) \right| \right] \leq 4D(x_1^n) \sqrt{\frac{v \log (n + 1)}{n}},
$$
where $D(x_1^n)$ is the $l_2$-radius of the set $\mathcal{F}(x_1^n)/n$.
The proof is left as an exercise, but it is not so obvious to me that how to approach this problem. I appreciate for any help.

Here is my attempted solution, however, I am missing a factor of $2$.
First using the fact that, given $X_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ is a collection of sub-Gaussian of parameter $\sigma$, then
$$
E \left[ \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |X_i| \right] \leq 2\sqrt{\sigma^2\log n}.
$$
(Indeed, this is the exercise 2.12 in Wainwright.)
Now observe that
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_if(X_i)
$$
is sub-Gaussian with parameter $$
\frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)^2}.
$$
Suppose $card(\mathcal{F}(x_1^n)) = M \leq (n + 1)^\nu$.
Then using the result about the expected maxima of sub-Gaussian, I obtain
$$
E \left[ \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i f(X_i) \right| \right]
\leq 2 D(x_1^n)\sqrt{\frac{\nu \log(n+1)}{n}}.
$$
However, the coefficient on the right is $2$ instead of $4$. I do not know if this is a typo in Wainwright or not.
